# Cropping large jpeg

Tags: c++, jpeg, large-files, crop

There is a task, to write a programm that will be crope a JPEG files. But the problem is that  some jpeg files has large sizes - hundreds of MegaBytes. So the question: Is it possible to crop a jpeg file, but without loading all file to the RAM, using something like fseek(), and decoding only the parts that needed.

Is that possible? If yes, maybe there is some libraries do the same.

Upd. All this will be used for the deep zoom technology. So when deep zoom will asking for a file, this program will give it, but this should be in real time

Comment: Have you made sure that the large files are actually a problem? Computers these days have gigs of RAM and when there's not enough physical memory you page it disc... Try and crop a large jpeg first to make to see if it will be a perf. issue. And... premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework project.

Comment: ok, but in perfect, this utility, should working in real-time, And there is some files(maps) that bigger. The largest is 4GB, to work with it in real time is impossible, if tou will load it to ram

Comment: What kind of system?  And why is 4 GB the limit?  The future is 64-bit!

Comment: 4gb is not a problem, problem in speed. Imagemagick need a lot of time  to crop this file, i thing because it is decoding jpeg to bitmap

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this.

The first is lossless cropping, where you don't decode the file all the way but work with the 8x8 DCT blocks. You'll need to use a library that has this capability, and it places some restrictions on the cropping ability. You can't crop to a boundary that isn't on the DCT square, which limits you to multiples of 8 or 16 depending on the subsampling in the file.

The second way is to use a library that allows you to read and write one line at a time. I know that the [IJG library](http://www.ijg.org/) can do this, and probably others as well. This is the easy way, but the downside is that the image goes through a decompression/recompression pass and will lose quality and/or be larger.

Comment: Thank a lot, I will try the first way